# html checkbox shows up below h2 tag

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML checkbox with an h2 inside the same div

```css
h2.childcares {
  font-family: Source Sans;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ff9f01;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcares" unchecked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="childcares"></label>
  <h2 class="childcares">Childcares</h2>
</div>
```

this is the display

[image]

I want the checkbox to be centered by the h2 tag

Comment: Running the code you provided *as is*, everything looks aligned well; maybe there's something else causing the issue? Can you check with DevTools if there's some additional margin or padding there?

Comment: @IvanS95 - thanks for putting this in a snippet.  When I run it on Chrome, I do see that the checkbox falls slightly below the center.  However, I'm beginning to believe I perhaps do not understand what ziggy's desired output is, as evidenced by our discussion below.

Comment: @AlexanderNied if its Chrome problem than I will accept your answer below. because your suggestion `vertical-align: middle ` did move the checkbox up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say give all the children a [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) style:

```css
h2.childcares { 
    font-family: Source Sans;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ff9f01;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 15px; 
}

.custom-control-label, 
.custom-control-input,
.childcares {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="childcares" unchecked>
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="childcares"></label>
   <h2 class="childcares">Childcares</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: also does `.childcares` refer to the checkbox id or the h2 tag class? (new to css here)

Comment: @ziggy `.childcares` refer to a class, `#childcares` would refer to an id :)

Comment: A dot (`.`) preceding the value indicates it is a class; a hash (`#`) preceding the value indicates an id.  As for the display, perhaps I am misunderstanding your intention.  When I run this on Chrome, it has all the elements nicely center aligned against the horizontal axis.  Is that not the desired result?

Comment: That's my take as well; running the code provided it actually shows the elements aligned correctly at the middle; I think there might be some other styles causing the issue

Comment: well this code is part of another div -- but i did not think it would effect it. so I will update the code -- because this code snippet alone works fine

Answer (score 0):

your code properly aligns checkbox in the middle, there might be a cache issue for you. Any how if you want it to set in middle you can add this single property in your css and your checkbox alignment gets locked.

```
h2.childcares {
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
```

please follow this below link it explains more clearly
[checkbox property alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)